# Dual y axis in Julia plots are on the same side

Tags: plot, julia

I'm using Plots with Pluto notebook in Julia, and trying to make a plot with dual y-axis:

```
begin
plot(randn(100), ylabel="y1", leg=:topright)
plot!(twinx(), randn(100)*10,
    c=:red,
    ylabel="y2",
    leg=:bottomright,
    size=(600, 400))
plot!(right_bottom=10mm)
end
```

However, the result is that both of y-axis are on the same side (left):

[image]

I'm not sure how to make one of them on the right side

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that works. To get displayed both labels in legends, just run the code twice:

```
begin
plot(randn(10), label="Primary yaxis", ylabel="y₁")
plot!(twinx(), 3*randn(10),
    c=:red, label="Secondary yaxis",
    ylabel="y₂",
    size=(400, 300))
plot!(framestyle=:box)
end
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I still get both of them on the left side. I'm using Pluto, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: It may be Pluto. I don't use use it.